# CryptEncrypt ignores HASH?

Tags: c, windows, cryptography

I am trying to make an application which uses AES 256 Encryption. Unfortunately i can't get it work. Maybe i didn't understand the crpytographic logic fully.

So it is working, but as far as i understand the hash contains the password. But if i change the password the output is the same. So it seems that `CryptEncrypt` ignoes the Hash.

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
 if ( !CryptAcquireContext( &hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT ) )
 {   
            printf( "\nCryptAcquireContext failed %d", GetLastError() );   
            return;    
 }
if ( !CryptImportKey( hProv, ( const LPBYTE )&keyBlob, sizeof( keyBlob ), 0, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hPubKey ) )
{
    printf( "\nCryptImportKey failed %d", GetLastError() );
    return;
}

if ( !CryptCreateHash( hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash ) )
{
    printf( "Error %x during CryptCreateHash!\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}

if ( !CryptHashData( hHash, ( PBYTE )wszPassword, cbPassword, 0 ) )
{
    printf( "Error %x during CryptHashData!\n", GetLastError() );
    return;
}

//if ( !CryptDeriveKey( hProv, CALG_AES_256, hHash, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey ) )//hKey
//{
//  printf( "Error %x during CryptDeriveKey!\n", GetLastError() );
//  return;
//}

if ( !CryptSetKeyParam( hPubKey, KP_IV, ivData, 0 ) )
{
    printf( "\nCryptSetKeyParam failed %d", GetLastError() );
    return;
}

DWORD size = ( DWORD )strlen( StringToEncrypt ) / sizeof( char );
//printf( "\nLength of string to encrypt = %d\n\n", size );
if ( !CryptEncrypt( hPubKey, hHash, TRUE, 0, ( LPBYTE )StringToEncrypt, &size, ( size / 16 + 1 ) * 16 ) )
{
    printf( "\nCryptEncrypt failed %d", GetLastError() );
    int a = GetLastError();
    switch ( a )
    {
        case NTE_BAD_HASH_STATE: printf( "NTE_BAD_HASH_STATE" ); break;
        case NTE_BAD_HASH: printf( "NTE_BAD_HASH" ); break;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "password" - usually known as the key - is in hPubKey.  The hHash is for generating a hash at the same time as the encryption is done.  Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But shouldn't i get a different result if i pass a Hash, and if i don't? Microsoft says: `If data is to be hashed and encrypted simultaneously, a handle to a hash object can be passed in the hHash parameter` Or am i misunderstandung something?

Comment: The ciphertext result only depends on the key and the plaintext.  It does not depend on the hash.